# Insert double number to mysql, change (.)

Tags: php, mysql, insert, double

I would like to insert a double or float number to mysql, for example **2371.80** €.
In my country we are writting **2371.80€** like **2.371,80€**. Can I insert number like **2.371,80€**??

I know that can i use `str_replace()`  and `length()` to add or change characters, but i want to do this when run `insert query`.

Also i tried to change unicode but nothing.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Are you including the  **€** symbol in the value to be added? Because then it stops being a double or float and starts being a character string.

Comment: yes a number like that can be inserted but the data type column in which you are entering the value should be made to **varchar**

Comment: NO! This is for example

Comment: € symbol is for example to explain how to use it

Comment: Read about numerical types in mysql documentation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you can't. That's the SQL standard and MySQL complies with it. Comma , is also used as values separator.

`INSERT INTO a(b,c) VALUES (3,4,5)` would be ambiguous.

or you can use

> varchar

for adding as string

Comment: I know it but i want it like double to calcualte easier

Comment: then you need format data before Inserting and after Selecting